# Odoo 8 - how to setup multivariant product - "add an item" button missing

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am trying to setup multivariant product in Odoo 8 (Ubuntu), but there is no "add an item" button on the product variant tab.

Also there is no create button in Sales / Config / Product Categories & Attributes / Attributes and Attributes Values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First , check users rights :**

- Go to Configuration -> Users -> Click the user
- Click Edit button
- Click Access rights
- Check Products variants

**Now, creating a Template (this is a basic process) :**

1. You have to create Variant Dimension Type :

   - Go to : Sales -> Configuration -> Products -> Variant Dimensions -> Dimension Types

Create one Dimension Type ( Say : Color)

2. You have to create Options for this dimension type :

   - Go to : Sales -> Configuration -> Products -> Variant Dimensions -> Dimension Options

Create new one + Click Dimension Type field and select "Color" + Enter Dimension Option Name : "green"

Repeat last step and create 3 or 4 colors.

3. Now we create a Product Template :

   - Go to : Sales -> Configuration -> Products -> Product Templates

Create a new Product Template, set its name and check the case "variant multiple" + click the tab "Variants"

In the first field (Dimension Type Name) , click "Add" and select the type we created earlier : "Color"

Then in next field click "Add all option" : alls colors should be listed now.

Scroll down and click "Generate/Update variants" : Now Products should be listed in lower field.

Save the Template by clicking the red button on top of the page.

Now you created some produtcs from this Template we created.

4. Now verify that product are created :

Go to : Sales -> products
Product should be listed here

Regards

Comment: this Step are for Odoo8 and if this doesn't work then you might wanna consider checking your security,

Comment: thank you, user rights, the only way I could do it is to log in as Admin, only the Step 3 I think is not necesarry anymore from version 8.